# Deleting my answer which was accepted

Tags: support, deletion

I wish to delete my own [incorrect answer to a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75193/euclidean-distance-vs-squared/75198#75198).  My answer was (for reasons beyond my understanding) marked as correct, although it was pointed out that my answer is incorrect.  Does deleting the accepted answer have any ("under the hood") consequences?

Note that this question shares a similar title to but was not strictly answered in [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/how-can-i-delete-an-answer-which-has-been-accepted).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe so - I've just deleted your answer, so now the OP *should* (I think) be free to choose a new answer as accepted.

As Theo points out, a meta post is not necessary to request this; simply flag your answer for moderator attention with an explanation that you'd like it deleted, and we will help out.

Also, I figure it couldn't hurt to include here the [official meta.SO explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) of the circumstances under which one can and cannot delete one's own posts.

Comment: Maybe it would be worth mentioning the possibility of flagging for moderator attention which certainly would suffice in clear cases like this?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would love to see what happens if you undelete it after the OP accepts another answer!!

Comment: @Asaf: I just did an experiment on one of my posts where I'd accepted my own answer; it turns out the accept checkmark is removed from the deleted answer once another answer is accepted, so it all works out.

Comment: @Zev: Oh, shame. I was hoping for this tremendous system crash. Chaos is fun! ;-)